# django dynamic select_related in template

Tags: django, model, python-3.4

I got two models:

```
class Location(models.Model): 
    location_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_code=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.location

class Host(models.Model): 
    host_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location=models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    host=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
    return "%s. %s" % (self.location.location, self.host)
```

it's a view for my template:

```
def index(request):
    locations=Location.objects.order_by('location')
    hosts=Host.objects.order_by('host')
    template=loader.get_template('ports/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'locations':locations, 'hosts':hosts},request))
```

I want to place two input selects in template, like this:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="location">
   {% for location in locations %}
    <option>{{location.location}}</option>
   {% endfor %}  
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="host">
        ?????? dynamic update depending on location's select
  </select>
```

And the second select will contain host. I need host's select to update dynamically when I change value in location's select.

Comment: OK, I can use select.onChange. But how could I get host values via Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this purely with django templating. You would need javascript to dynamically choose the appropriate values (JQuery would be a straightforward way)

You can make it easier, by making sure there are clear selectors that JQuery can use on the second dropdown, based on the model relationships.